# Function argument type inference and conditional type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to cover following case:

I have a function which accepts a boolean and returns value of `RealItem | ImaginaryItem` type. I'm using conditional type to narrow the return type based on `boolean` argument.

```
type RealItem = { color: string }
type ImaginaryItem = { description: string }

export function createItem<T extends boolean>(isReal: T): T extends true ? RealItem : ImaginaryItem

export function createItem<T extends boolean>(isReal: T): RealItem | ImaginaryItem {
  return isReal ? { color: 'red' } : { description: 'Crazy thing' }
}
```

My signatures seem to be working fine for following cases:

```
const a = createItem(true)      | typeof a -> RealItem
const b = createItem(false)     | typeof b -> ImaginaryItem


let isReal = true
const a = createItem(isReal)    | typeof a -> RealItem

let isReal = false
const b = createItem(isReal)    | typeof b -> ImaginaryItem
```

However if I wrap `createItem` into another function and pass `isReal` argument:

```
const itemsFactory = (isReal: boolean) => createItem(isReal)
```

TS seems to fail to deduct return type narrowed with conditional return type:

```
const a = itemsFactory(true)    | typeof a -> RealItem | ImaginaryItem
const b = itemsFactory(false)   | typeof b -> RealItem | ImaginaryItem
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIBKsCGAbAkuWBbeBeeAb3gGMB7NcgJwC54BncagSwDsBzeAXwhgQw4UHdimqQsuAsXgATWA1Kto4FuTb0mrTj1ChYAD2g1w8AGYBXNqVXqy1VNkk4APABV4h7G1kN4AI3JKVDYAPgAKFgZkdHo3AEo4zwNvX3hmCwQAfiRUTGw8ekFhUXFnfSMTcysbNTZ7R1hnd2TUv0DglDDI6Ly4xNz0Z3gAH3hikTYxCQLiUHh4B3ALanqomLR4HJIKKjp4AHIHWQOeeHoSeUVlWw1DgGFqFAAvSHSAC3YOU94QX9AAPQAwb5XCgChsJjwFAARmkSkaznCGVg8XB6ih-jhhARKCcBWR1EyaLAICBIOGYwmpRmYJAEKhKAATNIeht6B00CF4gRQg08U0Ces8iSGaZ-CzCMzCcTQEA)

I'm not gonna lie, the union type makes me very unhappy.

- **Is this some sort of limitation of TS capabilities in type interference?**
- **Can I help TS understand how to interpret higher function arguments?**

I know I could use type guards here, however they don't go well with my current code structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type information of `isReal` is essentially lost with the `itemsFactory` function since you specified `isReal` as a `boolean` here.

To fix this, you can also add the same generic type to the `itemsFactory` function:

```
const itemsFactory = <T extends boolean>(isReal: T) => createItem(isReal)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCGAbAksCBbKBeKBvKAxgPaJEBOAXFAM7BkCWAdgOZQC%20AUKJFMuvMybwyIVBmx4oAEwjUCDMMHpFGVWgxbsOHCAA8w5YFABmAV0YElKwmQRox6ADwAVKHrSMp1KACMiJBEYAPgAKemo4JCpnAEpot10PLyg6U2gAflgEFDRMKj4BIREHbT0DMiMzCytGGzsIBxcEpO8-APhgsIjs6LispAcoAB9efkFGYVFcvA4oKFtgUzJa8MjEKEz8YlJKKAByWyk99igqfBk5BRqqPYBhMngALxAUgAsmZmPOTg5iRlooPAJPJ6g4QqkIDE5nNfioAT5gbZ4PZciFjEhqJDodoOIgIEZVtkJBDYf8jPAAEyI0GowlIKHaPEE7pIKk4dGITGk%20FsurIhq0lmIBnaP4A%20i5agAMXglnILxwTXcEE8rX8eI6oTpiF62CCfJRGC6axiorh5IAzBIJRhpbLgPLwWQ0qaxUYfFacDb0Ha5SI0RjIdogA)